# $2^n + 1$ is prime $ \implies n$ is a power of $2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, fermat-numbers

I was wondering why I can't do this this way by proof by contradiction of the contrapositive. So I want to prove
$$2^n + 1 \quad \text{is prime} \implies n = 2^k \quad \text{for some} \ k\in \mathbb{Z}.$$
By contrapositive,
$$n \neq 2^k \quad \text{for all} \ k \in \mathbb{Z} \implies 2^n + 1 \quad \text{is composite.}$$

Then I want to prove by contradiction:
Suppose $n \neq 2^k \quad \forall k\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $2^n + 1$  is prime.
Why can't I give one counterexample to prove that this is false (contradiction)?
Since if $n:= 3$ then $2^3 + 1 = 9$ which is composite, hence, $2^n + 1$ being prime (hypothesis) cannot be true, so by proof by contradiction, $2^n +1$ must be composite?

Comment: Because you have to prove it for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Strictly speaking you also need $n\gt 0$, because $2^0 + 1 = 2$ is prime (but $0$ is not a power of $2$).

Comment: You want to "prove" that *All Nordic women have blonde hair* by exhibiting a Chinese lady with black hair?

Comment: @Math Lover I think it should be for all $k\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Hint: If $n$ is not a power of $2$, there is an odd $d>1$ such that $d\mid n$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Yes, you are right. It should be $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Do you really think that showing that $2^3+1$ is composite in this way shows that $2^5+1$ is composite or $2^6+1$ or $2^7+1$?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I find the choice of *duplicate* proposed to be bizarre.  Fermat primes are not (with the exception of $3$) Mersenne primes.  There is a Comment (the first under the Question) in the proposed duplicate connecting them, but neither the body of that Question or any of its Answers are pertinent here.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose there is a odd prime $p|n$. Then $n=p\cdot k$ for some natural $k$. Now we have:
$$ 2^{pk}+1 =(2^k+1)(2^{k(p-1)}-2^{k(p-2)}+...-2^k+1)$$

Clearly both factors are > 1 and thus a contradction.

Answer (score 3):

The question isn't to show that there is **one** $n$ that is not a power of $2$ with $2^n+1$ composite, it is to show that **for every** $n$ that is not a power of $2$, $2^n+1$ is composite.

Comment: I see; would my contrapositive and then contradiction (or just contrapositive) path lead to anything?

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the typical route to go about proving this statement.